# Enabling UDMA Mode 6 for a SATA II HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, speed, transfer

How would I go about enabling UDMA Mode 6 transfer for my Seagate Baracudda 7200.12 HDD ? HD tune tells me that it supports it but is operating at Mode 5. My motherboard is a ASUS P5B-MX WiFi/AP, uses the ICH7 chipset ( if I recall correctly ). I'm running Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check that you have all the latest drivers from the motherboard and the chipset. Check the manufacturer website and then also install and run [DriverMax](http://www.innovative-sol.com/drivermax/).

Check the Seagate website and see if they have any downloads available. They should have an utility which allows you to select the hard drive settings.